# Unable to get CoordinatorLayout LayoutParams in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-coordinatorlayout, coordinator-layout

I want to implement swipe to delete using `CoordinatorLayout`, so I created simple xml for each item of `RecyclerView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/simpleModelName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And simple Adapter

```
open class SwipeableAdapter(val list:ArrayList<SimpleModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SwipeableAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var nameTextView: TextView
        var coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout

        init {
            nameTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.simpleModelName)
            coordinatorLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): SwipeableAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.item_simple_model, viewGroup, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: SwipeableAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.nameTextView.text = list[position].name

        var swipe = SwipeDismissBehavior<View>()
        swipe.setSwipeDirection(SwipeDismissBehavior.SWIPE_DIRECTION_END_TO_START)
        swipe.setListener(object : SwipeDismissBehavior.OnDismissListener {
            override fun onDismiss(view: View?) {
            }

            override fun onDragStateChanged(state: Int) {
            }
        })

        Log.e("onBindViewHolder","layout "+viewHolder.coordinatorLayout.javaClass.toString())
        Log.e("onBindViewHolder","layout "+viewHolder.coordinatorLayout.layoutParams.javaClass.toString())
        val coordinatorLayoutParams = viewHolder.coordinatorLayout.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
        coordinatorLayoutParams.behavior = swipe

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }
}
```

The problem is with this line:

```
    val coordinatorLayoutParams = viewHolder.coordinatorLayout.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
```

I got crash with stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams
 at app.deadmc.swipeablelayout.SwipeableAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SwipeableAdapter.kt:43)
 at app.deadmc.swipeablelayout.SwipeableAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SwipeableAdapter.kt:12)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6508)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6541)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5484)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5750)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5589)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5585)
 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2231)
 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1558)
 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1518)
 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:610)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3719)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3135)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
```

Okay, started to check whats the problem,logged it, and found, that

```
        Log.e("tag","layout "+viewHolder.coordinatorLayout.javaClass.toString())
        Log.e("tag","layout "+viewHolder.coordinatorLayout.layoutParams.javaClass.toString())
```

Shows

```
12-29 13:46:16.310 19129-19129/? E/tag: layout class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
12-29 13:46:16.310 19129-19129/? E/tag: layout class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams
```

The questions are:

What am I doing wrong?
Why `CoordinatorLayout` gives me `RecyclerView$LayoutParams`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `coordinatorLayout` is a direct child of the `RecyclerView` and thus has `LayoutParams` appropriate for this relation. The children of the `CoordinatorLayout` will most likely have `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams`.

But you don't need a `CoordinatorLayout` to implement a swipe to delete action with a `RecyclerView`. It's supported directly with [`ItemTouchHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html) and the [`ItemTouchHelper.Callback.onSwiped()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html#onSwiped(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20int)) callback.

Comment: usually I use ItemTouchHelper, but wanted to check how it works with CoordinatorLayout. Will try to use parent views for it.

Comment: Then try it with the `nameTextView` view directly. It should have the `swipe` behavior then, I think. And it should have the correct `LayoutParams`.

Comment: I just wrapped with additional layout. And that works, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Layout params of a given view are meant to be used by the containing layout, i.e. the parent `ViewGroup`. So, as your `CoordinatorLayout` is inside the `RecyclerView`, it is `RecyclerView.LayoutParams`.

The view having `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams` is `@id/simpleModelName`, which will be laid out by the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Hope this clarifies it.